# How to make 2 buttons in xml stick together (cover the whole space) in a linear layout?

Tags: android, xml, image, layout, android-linearlayout

I am trying to make 2 buttons in a linear layout appear together or be closer then where there are now against each other but I am struggling to do so.

below is my xml with what it shows, is it possible to achieve what I want, I would really appreciate if someone could tell me how.

```
 <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <Button
                android:text="Person 1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/btnPerson1" />

            <Button
                android:text="Person 2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/btnPerson2" />
        </LinearLayout>
```

I want the PERSON 1 button and PERSON 2 button to come closes and or stick together
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set negative margin to both buttons.

```
android:layout_marginTop=-8dp
android:layout_marginBottom=-8dp
```

Comment: Thanks that works, I was doing the same with negative .margin but with just margin and not top and bottom

Comment: @Andrew . Thanks that it works for you.
Can you please accept my answer if its helpful.

Comment: I have accepted it, it shows a green tick on my screen.

Comment: Default buttons have 6dp vertical and 4dp horizontal inset. Use -4dp, -6dp, -4dp, -6dp (left, top, right, bottom) margins.

Comment: Negative margins do not work like this when `android:orientation="horizontal"`.

Answer (score 0):

add android:layout_margin="0" to buttons

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
<LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0dp">

        <Button
            android:text="Person 1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight=".5"
            android:id="@+id/btnPerson1" />

        <Button
            android:text="Person 2"
            android:layout_marginTop="-12dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight=".5"
            android:id="@+id/btnPerson2" />
    </LinearLayout>
```